# Beginner question about existence of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I am having problems understanding why a Laplace transform exists or not. Here is my math and logic, hopefully someone can point out where I am wrong.

$$f(t)=e^{at} \implies ℒ[e^{at}] = F(s)=\int_0^{\infty}\exp([a-s]t)dt$$

From this point I am at a loss both mathematically and notationally, but here I go anyways:

$$\implies \frac{1}{a-s}\lim_{t \to\infty}\exp([a-s]t)$$

According to Schaum's "Laplace transform":

*The Laplace transform  of f(t) is said to **exist** if the integral converges for some value of s; otherwise it does not exist.*

What does this mean for my case? The way I understand it is that $s>a$, because only then the integral will converge. Is this correct? And if it is, why can we just assume that $s>a$?

I am really frustrated, I have tried to look it up on the internet and here, but I just do not understand it.

Edited from $s>t$ to $s>a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $s$ and $a$ to be real, the integral defining $F(s)$ in your case converges provided $s>a$. This specifies the domain of $F$, which is the interval $(a,\infty)$. When $s$ is real, the transform is only intended to be defined for $s$ large enough to make the integral converge.

To understand this it may help to note that the Laplace transform produces another function, which may in fact have another domain.

Comment: $s$ isn't real it is complex.

Comment: @dustin This is why I adopted this caveat. When $s$ is complex you have a bit more to do, but I don't think the OP is dealing with the complex case. If it looks like they are, I will edit or delete my answer.

Comment: No, I have just begun and I am not dealing with complex cases. I understand that if there is some value of s that makes the integral converge, then the LT exists. I just think that it is strange that we can "assume that $s>a$" and just continue. I do realize that this is because I am not really understanding what I am doing. @dustin and Ian, thank you for trying to clarify it for me. Maybe LT is something I just have to work with for a while to understand better.

Comment: @Akitirija The LT exists as a function if the integral converges for some $s$. The LT, being a function, has a *domain* on which the integral converges. In your case this domain is $(a,\infty)$. It is not really that we are assuming $s>a$, it is that we are never putting $s \leq a$ into $F$, because it is not in the domain of $F$.

Comment: Would it be correct to say something like "The domain of the Laplace transform is $(a,\inf)$, because this is the interval for which the integrand $exp([a-s]t)$ converges"?

Comment: @Akitirija That's pretty much correct. (Technically you should say something like "because this is the interval for which $\int_0^\infty \exp([a-s]t) dt$ converges", but I know what you meant.) And again, as I commented before, here we are dealing only with the case where $s$ is real.

Comment: @Akitirija you should look at [this](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/laplace.pdf) because $s$ isn't real. You will see $s\in\mathbb{C}$, $s$ is the complex frequency variable, and mentioning of convergence is about the real part of $s$. It starts on page 4.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, dustin. But my sentence above is still correct, right? I am trying to get a very basic, but sound, understanding before I dive into more complex material ;)

Comment: @Akitirija yes we need $s$ is greater than $a$ but math is about being precise so what you should want to say is $\text{Re}\{s\} > a$

Comment: Thank you again, dustin. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

$s$ is complex of the form $s=\sigma +j\omega$ where $\sigma,\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j=\sqrt{-1}$, so for convergence, the real part of $s$ has to be greater than zero **when** we have $e^{-st}$. Now, let's take your example, we have that an exponential will decay or blow up. The argument of the exponential is $a-s < 0$ for $t\in(0,\infty)$ so $a<s$ or the integral will converge when $\text{Re}\{s\} > a$.

On the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) page, you will see the formal definition and that $s\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is not true that the real part of $s$ always has to be greater than zero. For example the Laplace transform of $e^{-t}$ converges for $Re(s)>-1$. Indeed this already appears later in your answer.

Comment: @Ian I just took the general form $e^{-st}$ and the example applied $e^{at}e^{-st}$. With that information, the OP should be able to set up the inequality needed for whatever case they encounter.

Comment: Allow me to be a bit more direct. "for convergence, the real part of $s$ has to be greater than zero" is in your first sentence. It is outright false. Please change it.

Comment: @Ian read the rest of sentence since we have $e^{-st}$. Then I continue saying let's look at your problem.

Comment: Where do we have $e^{-st}$, exactly? The way I'm reading your first sentence suggests that the Laplace transform of any function will never converge unless $Re(s)>0$. This is false. Please at least clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Ian we have $e^{-st}$ in the definition of the Laplace transform. $$\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

Comment: Yes. You can still have convergence when $Re(s) \leq 0$ if $f$ decays sufficiently fast. For example, the Laplace transform of $f(t)=e^{-t}$ converges if $Re(s)>-1$. Your answer suggests otherwise, or at least is not clear about what you mean.

Comment: @Ian I am well aware of that. I think you are getting off track here. If we take $a$ to be a negative number we have that. I am not saying all cases are real part is less than zero. I am saying for $e^{-st}$ the real part is.

Comment: I'm not off track; your first sentence is just not clear, because it's not clear which function's Laplace transform's convergence you are talking about in that sentence. Yes, the Laplace transform of $1$ (where the integrand would be just $e^{-st}$) converges only when $Re(s)>0$, but the Laplace transform of $e^{-t}$ converges when $Re(s)>-1$. You might stick to the OP's problem and say that the integrand defining the Laplace transform is $e^{(a-s)t}$, and then comment that $Re(a-s)<0$ is required for convergence. That would be clear. What you have now is not at all clear.

Comment: @Ian for you, it may not be clear but that doesn't apply to the entire population. You are extrapolating by multiplying by random functions. I didn't do that so why are you comparing that to these other functions makes no sense. I changed the word from since to when. That should make no bones about it.

Comment: There are no "random" functions here. Your first sentence suggests to me that the integral defining the Laplace transform of $f$ never converges unless $Re(s)>0$. Ostensibly this is "because there's a factor of $e^{-st}$", but this can get canceled by decay in $f$. Do you see how this interpretation is possible?

Comment: @Ian no it doesn't and you get (-1) for saying $s$ is real.

Comment: The -1 here was for insisting on dealing with the complex case after the OP's comment pointed out that they were only concerned with the real case.

Comment: @Ian $s$ is not real see the definition of the Laplace transform.

Comment: I am aware that in general $s$ is complex, and that more can be done with the Laplace transform with a complex argument. But plenty of books define the Laplace transform starting out with a real argument. Some don't even extend to the complex case at all. This is the typical approach in elementary ODE books, where they are not concerned with defining the inverse Laplace transform formally but are only concerned with using the Laplace transform with tables to solve ODEs. The OP is clearly following such a reference, judging by the comment on my answer.

Comment: @Ian just because they are lied to for simplicity of approach doesn't change the fact that $s$ is complex.